# How to find which dependency imports specific so file

Tags: android, dependencies, .so

I'm trying to get my app complaint to the 64-bit standard as Google expects: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

I analyzed my release apk and found a .so file: libtdm-5.0-96-jni.so

Tried to find it on my dependencies, but none of them have this name or something like that.

How do I find which dependency imported this .so file to my project?

Comment: Did you find the origin of this library?

Comment: No, I haven't...

Answer (score 1):

There is a gradle task called "dependencies". Execute this on your app module.